# Does JPA/Hibernate support custom types

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Does JPA/Hibernate support custom types? I thought by extending BigDecimal that would be enough for Hibernate to treat my type as a BigDecimal. This doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way I can make this work? I would rather avoid using @Embedded and @Embeddable if possible.

Type:

```
public class Money extends BigDecimal {

    public Money(String type) {
        super(type);
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Money inPocket;

    @Column(name = "InPocket")
    public Money getInPocket() {
        return inPocket;
    }

    public void setInPocket(Money amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I try this I get the following:

in the log:

```
SEVERE: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Exception Message

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [Person]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't support custom types, but hibernate does.  By their nature, custom types are vendor specific.

Here is hibernates custom type (AKA user type), which conveniently has an example of a money type:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom-ut